# Can I check in observer if a new item arrived to the observable?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'm accessing a memory area that belongs to a different computational process.
There are relatively infrequent changes in the area and I need to run a calculation when there are changes. I get notifications on change, but I need to wait a bit to make sure that no more changes are being made. I model it like this:

```
var readyToBeProcessed = changed
    .Select(x => DateTime.Now)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

However my calculations take quite some time, and it is possible that memory changes while I'm doing them. In this case I need to mark this particular round of calculations as invalid.

**But how do I know in my observer, when I finished the calculation, if another event arrived or not, while processing current event?** If there are no events arrive since I started the calculation, then it's valid and I can store the result.

In practice, it's very rarely, that the event arrive in the pattern (fast enough) that allow the calculation to become invalid, still I'd like to cater for this case.

*Note: I realize that I cannot guarantee to have always valid calculations. There is a small time between a change in memory is made and the time I receive the event. It is entirely possible, that the sequence is like this 1) I'm doing the calculation 2) memory changes 3) I finish the calculation and check the event, and decide the calculation is valid 4) memory change event arrives. I'm happy to live with this for now*

```
readyToBeProcessed.Subscribe(x =>
{
    Log.Info("Start work...");
    // Do calculation here
    ...
    // When finished
    if (Is there a new item)
    {
        Log.Info("There were changes while we worked... Invalidating");
        Invalidate();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Info("Succeeded");
    }
}, cancellationToken);
```

Is Reactive bad fit for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rx is actually a great choice here, I think, though you may need to model it a bit more explicitly.

Think of there being really five type of events: Item changes, do-Work-begins, and do-Work-ends, Invalidates, and Succeededs (I wish I could use better names, but I'm working off what you wrote).

Here's a marble diagram of how they would work:

```
t(sec)        : 0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9--10-11-12-13-14-15-16...
item-change   : *-*--**-----------------*-------------------------...
do-Work-begins: ---------------------*-----------------*----------...
do-Work-ends  : -------------------------*------------------*-----...
invalidate    : -------------------------*------------------------...
succeeded     : --------------------------------------------*-----...
```

We begin work once there has been a 5 second lull in item changes. If there has been any changes during the work time, we want to invalidate upon work-completion. If not, we want to observe success.

```
var doWorkBegins = changed
    .Select(x => DateTime.Now)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

var doWorkEnds = doWorkBegins
    .SelectMany(x => 
    {
        Log.Info("Start work...");
        // DoWork();
        //
        // should return an observable that returns a single value when complete.
        // If DoWork is just a void, then can use 
        // return Observable.Return(Unit.Default);
    });

var lists = changed
    .Buffer(() => doWorkEnds)
    .Publish().RefCount();

var succeeded = lists
    .Where(l => l.Count == 0);

var invalidate = lists
    .Where(l => l.Count > 0);

invalidate.Subscribe(x =>
{
        Log.Info("There were changes while we worked... Invalidating");
        Invalidate();
}, cancellationToken);

succeeded.Subscribe(x => 
{
    Log.Info("Succeeded");
}, cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, I would recommend you use a `Task` for keeping track of your work, then you can use:

```
readyToBeProcessed
.Select(evt => Observable.StartAsync<Unit>(async (cancellationToken) =>
{        
    //pass cancellationToken to work
    var result = await DoWork(cancellationToken);
    //test token if needed
    return result;
}))
.Switch()
.Subscribe();
```

When the next item arrives, the current token will be canceled.

Comment: `Switch` is the key here. You "project" the result of your calculation to another asynchronous value (a.k.a Future, task or an observable sequence of one value). Now you have a sequence of sequences. The `Switch()` operator will subscribe to the inner sequence when it arrives, but cancel that subscription (and the underlying `Task` when a newer inner sequence arrives. http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html

Comment: Switch won't work for two reasons: One, the "switch-key" is items, not readytobeprocessed. Secondly, his description made it sound like DoWork was full of side effects, which would only work if it properly honored the cancellation token. Since there's a method Invalidate, I'm assuming it doesn't.

Comment: `Invalidate` can be registered on the cancellation token though.